# How to upload file on server?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a file "@name.tgz" and I need to upload it on server with request

```
>  POST https://111.11.11.1:808/installagent
>     Date: ------WebKitFormBoundaryJ2Lbxaj6hqillFAB Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="@name.tgz"
> Content-Type: application/x-compressed
> 
> 
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryJ2Lbxaj6hqillFAB--

What i need to send  requests.post("https://111.11.11.1:808/installagent", ....)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it like this:

```
with open("file_to_upload.txt", "rb") as a_file:
file_dict = {"file_to_upload.txt": a_file}
response = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", files=file_dict)
```

So your code would be:

```
with open("@name.tgz", "rb") as a_file:
file_dict = {"@name.tgz": a_file}
response = requests.post("https://111.11.11.1:808/installagent", files=file_dict)
```

You can read more at: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-upload-a-file-with-post-in-python